# Mac reboots randomly with this crash dump (in watchdogd?)

Tags: crash

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f8f8f9ad5): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from com.apple.WindowServer in 120 seconds
service: com.apple.logd, total successful checkins since wake (141121 seconds ago): 14113, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: com.apple.WindowServer, total successful checkins since wake (141121 seconds ago): 14101, last successful checkin: 120 seconds ago

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffa41eedb720 : 0xffffff800ed1f5cd 
0xffffffa41eedb770 : 0xffffff800ee58b05 
0xffffffa41eedb7b0 : 0xffffff800ee4a68e 
0xffffffa41eedb800 : 0xffffff800ecc5a40 
0xffffffa41eedb820 : 0xffffff800ed1ec97 
0xffffffa41eedb920 : 0xffffff800ed1f087 
0xffffffa41eedb970 : 0xffffff800f4c2838 
0xffffffa41eedb9e0 : 0xffffff7f8f8f9ad5 
0xffffffa41eedb9f0 : 0xffffff7f8f8f97fa 
0xffffffa41eedba10 : 0xffffff800f454a8e 
0xffffffa41eedba60 : 0xffffff7f8f8f8cfe 
0xffffffa41eedbb60 : 0xffffff800f45dcb3 
0xffffffa41eedbca0 : 0xffffff800ee082b2 
0xffffffa41eedbdb0 : 0xffffff800ed25328 
0xffffffa41eedbe10 : 0xffffff800ecfbcc5 
0xffffffa41eedbe70 : 0xffffff800ed12aa2 
0xffffffa41eedbf00 : 0xffffff800ee30d05 
0xffffffa41eedbfa0 : 0xffffff800ecc6226 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[B435C72B-B311-3C67-8AA1-1D5CE0FAD429]@0xffffff7f8f8f8000->0xffffff7f8f900fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: watchdogd

Mac OS version:
19F101

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0: Tue May 26 20:41:44 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.121.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 54F1A78D-6F41-32BD-BFED-4381F9F6E2EF
Kernel slide:     0x000000000ea00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800ec00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800eb00000
System model name: Macmini8,1 (Mac-7BA5B2DFE22DDD8C)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 228223181267093
last loaded kext at 218872436980481: >AudioAUUC 1.70 (addr 0xffffff7f914e0000, size 28672)
last unloaded kext at 218303383214216: >AudioAUUC   1.70 (addr 0xffffff7f92638000, size 20480)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.1.0
com.intel.driver.EnergyDriver   3.5.5
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.1.0
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   5470
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@filesystems.smbfs  3.4.3
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    3.0.9
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.0.9
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.4
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.4
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.5f6
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>pmtelemetry    1
>AGPM   111.4.4
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.6
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.70.7
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.70.7
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.428
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.6
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!U!SCoexistentDriver   489.120.1
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!UTopCaseDriver    3430.1
>usb.!UHostBillboardDevice  1.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.120.2
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  3.0.9
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.4
|IOUSBUserClient    900.4.2
|IOAVB!F    850.1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.4
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 3.0.9
>!UAudio    323.1
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.5f6
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.5f6
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@kext.AMDSupport    3.0.9
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.4
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.5.4
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
|IOUSBMass!SClass   4.0.4
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.5f6
|IO!B!F 7.0.5f6
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.5f6
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>!AThunderboltPCIUpAdapter  2.5.4
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.121.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

What might be causing this?

Comment: I wish I knew! But you're not alone and it's been around for a long time: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250715149?page=34

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, it seems to be related to the VirtualBox software. In my case I just deactivate Sharing folders, Drag and Drop and No audio. However my iMac was still rebooting sometimes after immediate wake up from suspend.

So I reinstalled Catalina but didn't restore the TimeMachine backup. After Catalina was installed I created my user session and restored my personal files with iCloud (200GB subscription); the lager files were copied from the TimeMachine using Finder.

Now I can leave the iMac in suspend mode all the day waking up it several times and no BSD. Also I installed again VirtualBox but I didn't activate Sharing Folders, audio and drag and drop. What I can tell you is that sharing other devices with the VM like bluetooth sometimes reboot the machine.

Ubuntu VM seems to be working fine but RedHat/Oracle Linux VM crashes more frequently.

[image: OL7 VM]

Comment: Excellent information. Anything that installs a kernel extension is suspect, especially something with so many pervasive low level modifications as VBox needs to run the way it was designed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with one panic report is you don’t know if this program caused the issue or just was the first program to break a leg when it fell in to the open void left when the actual culprit removed the man hole cover, so to speak.  You could be just blaming the victim if you assume a problem exists in the `watchdogd` process.

Until you’re sure what’s causing this and can reproduce it, you may be better off following some excellent guidance to be sure it’s not a known bug or something being caused by a peripheral.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200553